# Who was Ved-Vyasa?

Tags: mahabharata, vyasa

Krishna Dvaipayana Veda Vyasa also known as VEdvyasa was a single person or an institute?  I believe it's an institute and everybody of it, works as Vedvyasa.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting a brief answer.

Veda Vyasa, in a literal sense, is a title. It means - the compiler of Vedas.

In every Dwapara Yuga, a person who is qualified with certain traits of Sri Vishnu (omniscience) takes up the role of Vyasa. [Vishnu Purana (Book 3, Chapter 3)](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm) gives a list of vyasas belonging to this Manvantara, where in Sri Krishna Dwaipayana is the 28th Vyasa of the current Vaivaswata manvantara:

> In the first Dwápara age the distribution was made by Swayambhu (Brahmá) himself; in the second, the arranger of the Veda (Veda-vyása) was Prajápati (or Manu); in the third, Uśanas; in the fourth, Vrihaspati; in the fifth, Savitri; in the sixth, Mrityu (Death, or Yama); in the seventh, Indra; in the eighth, Vaśisht́ha; in the ninth, Sáraswata; in the tenth, Tridháman; in the eleventh, Trivrishan; in the twelfth, Bharadwája; in the thirteenth, Antaríksha; in the fourteenth, Vapra; in the fifteenth, Trayyáruńa; in the sixteenth, Dhananjaya; in the seventeenth, Kritanjaya; in the eighteenth, Rińa; in the nineteenth, Bharadwája; in the twentieth, Gotama; in the twenty-first, Uttama, also called Haryátmá; in the twenty-second, Veńa, who is likewise named Rájaśravas; in the twenty-third, Somaśushmápańa, also Trińavindu; in the twenty-fourth, Riksha, the descendant of Bhrigu, who is known also by the name Válmíki; in the twenty-fifth, my (PARÁŚARA's) father Śakti was the Vyása; I (PARÁŚARA) was the Vyása of the twenty-sixth Dwápara, and was succeeded by Jaratkáru; the Vyása of the twenty-eighth, who followed him, was Krishńa Dwaipáyana. These are the twenty-eight elder Vyásas, by whom, in the preceding Dwápara ages, the Veda has been divided into four. In the next Dwápara, Drauńi (the son of Drońa) will be the Vyása, when my son, the Muni Krishńa Dwaipáyana, who is the actual Vyása, shall cease to be (in that character).

A handy Wiki page is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasa_(title)) for quick reference.

This implies that the previous six manvantaras (each of which comprised of about 71+ mahayugas, which again includes at least 71 dwapara yugas) had over 6*71 Vyasas = 426. We have the 28th Vyasa now in this manvantara. We have another 7 Manvantara all within this Kalpa (which is just one day of Sri Brahma). The list repeats.

The reason i say that a person takes up the role of Vyasa is that, Ashwattama, who fought on the kaurava side in the Mahabharatha will be the next Vyasa. The list gives many other interesting names including Valmiki, the author of Valmiki Ramayana as the 24th Vyasa.

So, answering your question, Veda Vyasa is not an institute per say but a status such as Indra or Manu.

Answer (score 1):

Swami Nikhilananda writes in his *General Introduction* to *The Upanishads, A New Translation* (pp 2-3):

> In the Puranas it is stated that Vyasa was commanded by Brahma to make a compilation of the Vedas. Vyasa is reputed to be the author of the *Mahabharata* of which the *Bhagavad Gita* forms a part (Nikhilananda's footnote: The authorship of several Hindu scriptures is ascribed to Vyasa. Either there was more than one Vyasa, or other Indian writers, following a well known custom by means of which importance was often given to books in ancient times, published or circulated their own works under the name of a great philosopher). He lived at the time of the battle of Kurukshetra. With the help of four disciples, so the tradition goes, this great saint and poet arranged the Vedasin four books, namely the Rik, Yajur, Saman, and Atharva. He was thus the classifier of the Vedas, though not their author.

Thus Ved Vyasa is the one who compiled the four vedas and the Mahabharata. There is no certainty as to whether other works ascribed to him were actually him or others.